# PHP: displaying NULL but actually contains data

Tags: php, var-dump, mysqli

product table structure is given below

```
    CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `unit_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `orignalCost` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `saleprice` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk-to-uom` (`unit_id`),
  KEY `fk-to-brand` (`brand_id`),
  KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk-to-brand` FOREIGN KEY (`brand_id`) REFERENCES `brands` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `products_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=230 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Can someone please tell me what mistake i'm making as var_dump() displays the NUll values......is there any mistake in mysqli_fetch_array? it is showing like that "array(1) { [0]=> NULL } "

```
$selected_items_values = $_POST['product_id']; 
   $prices = [];
   foreach($selected_items_values as $prud)
   {
     if(isset($prud))
     {
      $priceSql = "SELECT saleprice from products where id = ' $prud ' ";
      $price=mysqli_query($db,$priceSql);
      $price = mysqli_fetch_array($price);
      array_push($prices , $price);
      var_dump($prices);

     } 
  }
```

Comment: Don't add variables to your query like that, you are wide open to SQL injection. Always use prepared statements! The problem you have is because of the spaces `' 
$prud '` i think. If you remove the spaces, I think the query will work, but it's still not good.

Comment: As stated in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-array-returnvalues), `mysqli_fetch_array()` returns `null` when there are no more results to fetch (understand: your query have no results).

Comment: it doesnt work even when i remove the spaces

Comment: var_dump your query, run it on your db. see the result. Side note: select them all at the same time using the `IN` operator.

Comment: string(47) "SELECT saleprice from products where id = '44' "query displaying that result

Comment: Don't run queries in a loop like this. Use `SELECT...WHERE...IN...`, send the query once and get all the results back in one result set.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular i dont know how to put quries like that

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### EDITED ANSWER

Here is sample table I've created. (I removed foreign keys)

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
 `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `category_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
 `unit_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `brand_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `orignalCost` int(30) NOT NULL,
 `saleprice` int(30) NOT NULL,
 `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Here is sample insert statements

```
INSERT INTO `products`VALUES (NULL, '1', 'name1', '1', '1', '100', '200', '0');
INSERT INTO `products`VALUES (NULL, '2', 'name2', '2', '2', '100', '200', '0');
INSERT INTO `products`VALUES (NULL, '3', 'name3', '3', '3', '100', '200', '0');
INSERT INTO `products`VALUES (NULL, '4', 'name4', '4', '4', '100', '200', '0');
INSERT INTO `products`VALUES (NULL, '5', 'name5', '5', '5', '100', '200', '0');
INSERT INTO `products`VALUES (NULL, '6', 'name6', '6', '6', '100', '200', '0');
```

Here is sample data I've entered.

```
+----+-------------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+
| id | category_id |  name | unit_id | brand_id | orignalCost | saleprice | deleted |
+----+-------------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|  1 |      1      | name1 |    1    |     1    |     100     |    200    |    0    |
+----+-------------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|  2 |      2      | name2 |    2    |     2    |     100     |    200    |    0    |
+----+-------------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|  3 |      3      | name3 |    3    |     3    |     100     |    200    |    0    |
+----+-------------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|  4 |      4      | name4 |    4    |     4    |     100     |    200    |    0    |
+----+-------------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|  5 |      5      | name5 |    5    |     5    |     100     |    200    |    0    |
+----+-------------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|  6 |      6      | name6 |    6    |     6    |     100     |    200    |    0    |
+----+-------------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

Here is db connect get all data via PHP.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name");
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `products`;");
var_dump($query);
```

Here is the result of above. You can see I have 6 rows.

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 8
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 6
    [type] => 0
)
```

In order to loop through php object use foreach

```
foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
  var_dump($value);
}
```

Foreach result goes like

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [category_id] => 1
    [name] => name1
    [unit_id] => 1
    [brand_id] => 1
    [orignalCost] => 100
    [saleprice] => 200
    [deleted] => 0
)

Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [category_id] => 2
    [name] => name2
    [unit_id] => 2
    [brand_id] => 2
    [orignalCost] => 100
    [saleprice] => 200
    [deleted] => 0
)

It continues like that...
```

In order to get only `saleprice` use it like below.

```
foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
  var_dump($value['saleprice']);
}
```

So this is how you can get. Rest of it up to you whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: var_dump($selected_items_values); shoeing that values array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "39" [1]=> string(2) "40" } array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "39" [1]=> string(2) "40" }

Comment: I don't see any problem. Can you connect the database correctly? Can you share the result of this query ```$query = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `products`;");```

Comment: object(mysqli_result)#1 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: You only have one row in your table but you loop many values. This is the error. Probably the ids you loop doesn't exist in the table

Comment: table contains 10 rows when i eecute the query on phpmyadmin

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I suggested you `count` function and that returned one result. So what is the problem then ? You send values `39` and `40` do you have these ids in your table ?

Comment: yes these ids are in table but it cant fetch the saleprice from products table

Comment: Okay I need more information than I will simulate your table in my server to check what is problem. Can you run this SQL code `SHOW CREATE TABLE products` then click options -> Full Text -> Go. After running this code it will return you create table function. Paste it to your question. After that share a few data of these table. Then I wil try to simulate SQL query and PHP statement for your.

Comment: @ermaan question is updated kindly check that

Comment: thanks for this effort,,but it is working fine when i select single product but for multiple products when i put the query in foreach loop and put WHERE condition then it prints NULL...

Answer (score -1):

Aside from bugs specific to your implementation, there are two significant issues with this code:

- You're running a query in a loop, multiplying the number of queries you're doing and creating additional database traffic.
- You're concatenating untrusted data into your query, leaving yourself open to SQL Injection

The answer to the first problem is to use `SELECT...WHERE...IN...`, thus selecting all the required data in one query
The second issue is solve by the use of prepared statements. For variable length data they can be fiddly to set up, but the improved security and performance is worthwhile.

For your example we need to get to a query of the form

```
SELECT `saleprice` FROM `products` WHERE `id` IN (?,?,?);  // could be any number of placeholders here.
```

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','schema');
    // create the placeholders
    $paramList = str_repeat("?,", count($_POST['product_id']));
    $query = "select saleprice from products where id in (".trim($paramList, ',').")";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    // create a string of parameter types
    $types = str_repeat('s', count($_POST['product_id']));  // All $_POST values are strings.
    // Now bind the data to the query
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$_POST['product_id']); // Use the ... spread operator to unpack the array
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($resultData);
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $resultData;
        echo "<br>\n";
    }
```

Credit: Code taken from [this blog](https://www.pragmanotdogma.com/the-blog/29-perpared-statements-binding-an-array-of-parameters-to-an-in-clause)

Comment: when var_dump($resultData); is executed it also prints NULL.